# Unique query give me duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database in SQL Server and one table which I have to use to display unique values base on `column_one` without using `distinct` so I came up with solution:

```sql
select p.id, p.one, two, w.five, p.eight
from table_one p with (nolock)
join table_two w with (nolock) on w.one = p.one
where
w.eight between convert(date, '10/05/2020', 103) and dateadd(d, 7, convert(date, '10/05/2020', 103)) and
p.twelve = 2 
and p.id in (SELECT max(id) FROM table_one a with(nolock) GROUP BY two)
order by p.id desc
```

and I should get two rows, but I have 3, second row is duplicated? Why is that? I was trying to googling some examples and I found my solution as one of them. So what is wrong with it? Any suggestion will be helpful.

PS. I can confirm that subquery `select max(id)...` give me unique values.

**EDITED**
Sorry for missing that example earlier.
I hope is more clear now, what I want achieve.

```
table_one 
id | one      |  two | eight| twelve
-------------------------------------
1  |  value_1 | r1c2 | r1c8 | 2
2  |  value_1 | r2c2 | r2c8 | 2
3  |  value_2 | r3c2 | r3c8 | 2
4  |  value_2 | r4c2 | r4c8 | 2

table_two 
id | one      | five | eight
---------------------------------
1  |  value_1 | r1c5 | 22/03/2020
2  |  value_1 | r2c5 | 24/03/2020
3  |  value_2 | r3c5 | 24/03/2020
4  |  value_2 | r4c5 | 25/04/2020

result expected:
id | one     | two    | eight
-----------------------------------
2  | value_1 |  r2c2  | 24/03/2020
4  | value_2 |  r4c2  | 25/04/2020
```

I think I figured it out, but please correct me if I am wrong, is that because I am `JOIN`ing table on column `one` which is not unique?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Strangers on the web have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Well we don't see your data. So it's difficult to say. But if, e.g. table_one has 2 rows and one row of table_two corresponds to row 1 of table_one and 2 rows of table_two correspond to row 2 of table one, then you will get 3 rows in total. And since there is neither a DISTINCT nor a GROUP BY in the outer query, duplicates will not be eliminated.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause and `p.two = 2` condition on `varchar` values is an error.

Comment: Your example data has no dates in the range specified in the query. So your query should return no rows. Column `two` seems to contain texts like `'r1c2'`, but you filter with `p.two = 2`. Please match your query with your example data, otherwise we do not understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I am an idiot, my mistake. `p.two` should be totally different column which I do not want include in my `select` part, only to use it as condition. I edited my query I believe now it make more sense.

Comment: This does still not yield 3 rows, since the date range starts at `10/05/2020` but you have only dates in March and April. It should really be possible to reproduce the wrong behaviour, before trying to fix it.

Comment: The first thing you should have told us is **what data you want to select**. You show two rows for value_1 in table_one, but your result only contains one of them. Why? And why do you choose the second row and not the first one? What rule do you want to apply here? table_two also has two rows for value_1. Again, you only show one of them in your results. Again you dismiss the first row and pick the second, so again the question: Why this row? What is the rule you use for picking that row?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult without sample data and expected output, but I think that the following approach using `ROW_NUMBER()` is a possible option. You need to use the correct columns in the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select 
        p.id, p.one, p.two, w.five, p.eight,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.two ORDER BY p.id DESC) AS rn
    from table_one p with (nolock)
    join table_two w with (nolock) on w.one= p.one
    where 
        w.eight between convert(date, '10/05/2020', 103) and dateadd(d, 7, convert(date, '10/05/2020', 103)) and
        p.two = 2
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER by t.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

That's true because when you join two tables on `one` column and it has `duplicates values` in that field, you get duplicate rows in your results. for your task, you can use `window functions` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select 
        p.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY w.one ORDER BY w.eight DESC) AS rn
    from table_one p
    join table_two w on w.one= p.one
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER by t.id asc
```